# Recursively resetting unmerged paths files

Tags: git

After a merge, I have a set of files that are unmerged and under "both modified" status.
How do I recursively reset these files so that they are no longer staged for commit?
After unstaging them, I was going to do a git checkout to just keep the changes in the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

When the file status is **both modified**, it means the file has conflicts that must be solved (unless `rerere` is enabled and it could solve them).

I believe you want to solve all conflicts by picking the files from one side of the merge:

- *ours*: the branch you have currently checked out.
- *theirs*: the branch you are merging into the current one.

The easiest way to do that is using the `--ours` or `--theirs` flags of `git checkout` command:

```
git checkout --ours -- PATHS...
git add PATHS...
```

Note that the checkout will solve the conflicts in the file by using the version from one of the merge sides. After that, it is needed to run `git add` to stage the file. If you used `--ours`, the `git add` will stage no modifications (the file will not appear on `git status` output) and you can proceed with the merge as usual.

Comment: so how would  match any number of files with the same name?  What about all files under a subdirectory? What would PATHS look like?

Comment: @user994165 `PATHS...` is a list of files or directories separated by spaces. Git looks for all files recursively inside directories. *Caution:* `git add` will also add untracked files too, so to stage all tracked files in the repository (you can't specify a path in this case) use, for instance, `git add -A` or finish the merge with `git commit -a`.